# Alter statement to change datatype of a column form NUMBER(4 ) to NUMBER in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

what is the ALTER Statement to change datatype of a column form NUMBER(4) to NUMBER in oracle

Answer (score 3):

Try this SQL statement:

```
alter table yourtable modify yourcolumn number;
```